# Combining and splitting assignment in Haskell IO do block

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I /think/ I have a similar misunderstanding of the language in two places involving how variable assignment works in do blocks, involving the IO monad. Could you help me understand (1) is it the same misunderstanding, (2) how to clear it up (in an answer, and maybe specifically if you have a favorite reference on the subject)?

I find that I can perform an operation successfully when it is all one line, but not when I try to split into 2 for readability.

**Part I: Turning 1 line into 2**

Why does this work?

```
ipg :: IO ()
ipg = do
  conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo { connectHost = "0.0.0.0"}
  res <- execute conn "INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (?, ?)" $ MyRecord (Just 200) (Just"Test")
  print res
```

But this not work

```
ipg :: IO ()
ipg = do
  conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo { connectHost = "0.0.0.0" }
  q <- "INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (?, ?)" $ MyRecord (Just 200) (Just"Test")
  res <- execute conn q
  print res
```

Gives me:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘IO a0’
            with actual type ‘q0 -> IO GHC.Int.Int64’
Probable cause: ‘execute’ is applied to too few arguments
In a stmt of a 'do' block: res <- execute conn q
```

The difference between the first and second being trying to store the query portion in q.

**Part II: Turning 2 lines into 1**

Why does this work:

```
myinput :: IO ()
myinput = do
  putStrLn "Please input a number."
  mynum :: Int  <- readLn  
  print mynum
```

But this not work?

```
myinput :: IO ()
myinput = do
  mynum :: Int <- readLn $ putStrLn "Please input a number."
  print mynum
```

Gives me

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘IO () -> IO Int’
            with actual type ‘IO a0’
The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
execute conn "INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (?, ?)" $ MyRecord (Just 200) (Just "Test")
```

, the left-hand side of the `$` operator is `execute conn "INSERT…"`, and the right-hand side is `MyRecord …`. That is, you're calling `execute` with three arguments: the connection, the query, and the parameters. That’s the first problem:

```
q <- "INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (?, ?)" $ MyRecord (Just 200) (Just "Test")
res <- execute conn q
```

Here, the left-hand side of the `$` operator is the string `"INSERT…"`, and the right-hand side is the parameters. You're trying to call a string, then pass the result as the second argument to `execute`.

If `q` could be some strange type that represented two arguments, though, it probably wouldn’t be an `IO a`. You’re looking to just name a value with `let`, not run an action.

This should work:

```
ipg :: IO ()
ipg = do
  conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo { connectHost = "0.0.0.0" }
  let query = "INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (?, ?)"
  let parameters = MyRecord (Just 200) (Just "Test")
  res <- execute conn query parameters
  print res
```

---

```
myinput :: IO ()
myinput = do
  mynum :: Int <- readLn $ putStrLn "Please input a number."
  print mynum
```

This one just doesn’t make a lot of sense. Maybe it’s a misunderstanding of the `$` operator? `$` is mostly just a way to write expressions without using parentheses; `f $ x` is equivalent to `f x`, but the `$` has low precedence, so you can write `f $ 1 + 2` instead of `f (1 + 2)`.

Anyway, I’ll loosely translate it into Python for you, if that helps:

```python
def myinput():
    mynum = int(input(print("Please input a number.")))
    print(mynum)
```

If you want to sequence the `readLn` and `putStrLn` actions, you can use the `>>` operator (which is what `do` is doing behind the scenes):

```
myinput :: IO ()
myinput = do
  mynum :: Int <- putStrLn "Please input a number." >> readLn
  print mynum
```

That’s not very good for readability most of the time, though. (`a >> b` will also discard the result of `a` without complaint, whereas `do { a; b }` will give a compiler warning if discarding something that isn’t `()`.)

Comment: Got it, so these are unrelated problems.  The first was just not checking that the execute function took 4 arguments, and python-habit that I needed to query = "myquery {}".format(args); execute(query).  The second needed a sequential operator.  If I needed parens to show order of operations explicitly, rather than use $, I would have had to have done:

mynum :: Int <- (putStrLn "Please input a number." >> readLn)