# View non-exposed library functions while developing in Haskell

Tags: haskell, development-environment

I made a mistake [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193147/combining-and-splitting-assignment-in-haskell-io-do-block) that could have been solved by viewing

```
:t myfunctionofinterest
```

for a function I was using in a library.

However, when I am in my project root, and run

```
$ stack ghci
```

And my Main.hs has:

```
import MyLib
```

And my module does:

```
module MyLib {
  bunchOfFunctions -- but not myfunctionofinterest
} where

import SomeDB.ModuleThatExposes -- myfunctionofinterest

myfunc :: IO ()
myfunc = do
  myfunctionofinterest a b c -- place where I misuse myfunctionofinterest and could have used :t on it to see it had 3 args
```

I can't `:t` myfunctionofinterest in the main since it's not exposed, nor does `Import MyLib.myfunctionofinterest` explicitly 
help, since it was something defined in an import. While I know I could expose it then check it, `:a` to compile, and then edit the lib to hide it again, is there  anything that allows that more quickly and directly?

This seems like it must be a common pattern.  What do you do when you need to check the type of something used in a library as you develop?

Comment: `import MyModule` will work if `MyModule` is in `exposed-modules` or `other-modules` in your cabal file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting the [GHCi docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-scope):

> The `:module` command provides a way to do two things that cannot be done with ordinary import declarations:
>
> - `:module` supports the `*` modifier on modules, which opens the full top-level scope of a module, rather than just its exports.

The additional `*` makes GHCi load the bytecode version of the module. This will not be as performant, but you'll get access to unexported bindings.

Example:

```
λ> :m *MyLib
λ> :t myfunctionofinterest
```

If you get

```
module 'MyLib' is not interpreted; try ':add *MyLib' first
```

you may have to do `:load` first (the advice about `:add` doesn't always do the trick):

```
λ> :l *MyLib
λ> :m *MyLib
λ> :t myfunctionofinterest
```